# A Matrix Lie group consisting of upper triangular matrices

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am trying to solve an exercise that involves a matrix Lie group.

[image]

I am having issues with b) and c). Here are my ideas so far:

b) In order for $G$ to be a Lie Group, it needs to be shown that it is a smooth manifold. I started by observing that the elements of $G$ are uniquely determined by the choice of $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $H$ denote the upper halfplane in $\mathbb{R}^2$. We can define a map

$$
\varphi: G \to H, 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b      \\
0 & a^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}
\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
b \\
a
\end{pmatrix}
$$

This map is invertible. I would like to show that $\varphi$ and its inverse are $C^{\infty}$. In this case $\varphi$ would be continous such that $G=\varphi^{-1}(H)$ would be an open set in the smooth manifold $R^{n \times n}$ and therefore a smooth manifold itself. In particular $(G,\varphi)$ would form a smooth structure.

I am unsure how to prove differentiability. If I regard $\begin{pmatrix}
a & b      \\
0 & a^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}$
as a vector of the form $(a,b,a^{-1})$ then I could argue that the partial derivatives of $\varphi$ exist and are continous. But I'm not sure whether this goes through.

c) $\mathfrak{g}$ is the tangent space to $G$ at the identity $I_2$. Let $E_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a matrix such that the entry at $(i,j)$ is $1$ and $0$ otherwise. Let $T \in \mathfrak{g}$. Then there is a curve $\gamma: (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) \to G$ such that $\gamma(0)=I_2, \gamma'(0)=T$. Then

$$
\gamma(t)
=\begin{pmatrix}
a(t) & b(t)      \\
0 & a^{-1}(t)
\end{pmatrix}
=a(t) E_{11}+b(t) E_{12}+a^{-1}(t) E_{22}.
$$

Differentiating and evaluating at $t=0$ yields

$$
\gamma'(0)
=a'(0) E_{11}+b'(0) E_{12}+(a'(0))^{-1} E_{22} \tag{1}.
$$

We have $\text{det}(\gamma(t))=a(t) a^{-1}(t)=1$. Differentiating and evaluating at $t=0$ yields

$$
a'(0)=-(a'(0))^{-1}. \tag{2}
$$

From (1) and (2) I get the representation

$$
\gamma'(0)
=a'(0) \text{diag}(1,-1)+b'(0) E_{12}. 
$$

So $X=\text{diag}(1,-1), Y=E_{12}$ is a basis of $\mathfrak{g}$. But now I do not see how to compute $[X,Y]$. I know that $[ \cdot, \cdot]: \mathfrak{g} \times \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$ is a bilinear map satisfying $[X,Y]=-[Y,X]$. But I do not see how to derive an explicit formula.

\Edit: In this case, $[X,Y]$ is to be taken as $[X,Y]=XY-YX$, so a direct computation yields $[X,Y]=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2      \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$
So there is no issue at all with c).

Comment: There is a theorem that says something like: if your manifold is defined by $f(x) = c$ (constant) and $f$ is $C^r$ then the manifold is $C^r$ (r times continuously differentiable). Like the inverse function theorem or something? And here you are defined by the equation $ad = 1$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_theorem

Comment: How do you define the Lie algebra of a Lie. You have already stated that, for you, the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ is, as a vector space, $T_eG$. But how do you define $[X,Y]$ when $X,Y\in\mathfrak g$?